# Getting error while running macro on different worksheet but on same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the following error runtime

> error'1004', select method of range class failed

When trying to run the code below on different worksheet but on same workbook.

```
Sub AdministrationReport()

Dim report               As Workbook
Dim admiistration        As Workbook
Dim wbPath               As String

'report is the active workbook where data is being pasted
Set report = ActiveWorkbook ' (till here it opens new workbook - I have deleted that code to shorten the question)

' set administration to Open workbook from where data will be copied
Set administration = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
administration.Worksheets("Administration_POWHS Standardis").Range("A2:j100").Copy Destination:=report.Worksheets("administration").Range("A2:j100")
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'this is to format report data    
Set report = ActiveWorkbook

**report.Worksheets("administration").Range("a2:d100").Select**- stuck here

With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 90
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `Select` the Range, just use the `With` statement below (it will work for you running it from every sheet):

```
With report.Worksheets("administration").Range("A2:D100")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 90
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
End With
```

Comment: @
Shai Rado  was that because using .select was conflicting as we can only select one sheet at a time as active sheet?

Comment: @Vijay if you are trying to select a range on a different sheet than the one currently set as `ActiveSheet` , then you need to first select that sheet, and only then select the range. In any way, it's recommended to avoid using `Select` and `Activate` if possible (like in my answer). is it working for you now ?

Comment: yes its working well now, thanks for explaining in detail, much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
report.Worksheets("administration").Select
```

before

```
report.Worksheets("administration").Range("a2:d100").Select
```